# Index file for a subdirectory through CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to do a perfectly conventional thing: I am using
CloudFront / S3 to host a static website, but I also want to host
another website in a *subdirectory*.  Following the instruction, I
believe I got S3 to work

```
 % curl -v http://mydomain.me.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/c
> GET /c HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomain.me.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< x-amz-error-code: Found
< x-amz-error-message: Resource Found
< x-amz-request-id: 9BB13A73FFB4503E
< x-amz-id-2: 3JX26tNdHi1irPbFJS7E1BifwliygqRZsZIc/qZptjBqBjjmGL7YGK6xfG23GZR70R0Ou+3ZAiM=
< Location: /c/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 313
< Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 01:58:08 GMT
< Server: AmazonS3
```

So `/c` is redirecting to `/c/`, which I believe is correct, and that new location definitely serves correctly:

```
% curl -v http://mydomain.me.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/c/
> GET /c/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomain.me.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: BD0wdDnhonp7Y5i2b7mUDVbIXKYu4O52YPUKVQx5GDaLW5hmDzcrsF/EixdksCtkt/NK6Bg24hY=
< x-amz-request-id: 7F11B109218EF9ED
< Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 01:58:11 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 01:31:59 GMT
< x-amz-version-id: zSq5IxE3Ug8oG5SSW.lZsCYydp42.h.4
< ETag: "7999ccd49fe930021167ae6f8fe95eb6"
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 36
< Server: AmazonS3
<
```

And it actually gives me my file.  But when I try to go through CloudFront for `/c`:

```
 % curl -v https://mydomain.me/c
> GET /c HTTP/2
> Host: mydomain.me
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/2 403
< content-type: application/xml
< date: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 01:59:43 GMT
< server: AmazonS3
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 58b53da3f7d231b76d30fcffbf4945a1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: SFO20-C1
< x-amz-cf-id: PSjqsinkkfheUfhEPVYbbujMqemugFbrYxM-pQMIihMk3dpp2W4Bmw==
```

and it downloads the familiar S3 access denied.  For `/c/`, it is even weirder:

```
 % curl -v https://mydomain.me/c/
> GET /c/ HTTP/2
> Host: mydomain.me
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: application/x-directory; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 0
< last-modified: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 01:30:44 GMT
< x-amz-version-id: 4L.jn6WG3emcGutRuwEZv_lE0aO07AGR
< accept-ranges: bytes
< server: AmazonS3
< date: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 02:00:31 GMT
< etag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
< x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 37d64bca4c93552139fb3a85c9c4a119.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: SFO20-C1
< x-amz-cf-id: r5lS4QTmg07XhIXRlXsNJ4qcJaWXfj5Ik9fXZPY_dzLjED-A2MhBiA==
```

It "works", but it returns an empty file, which it says is a directory listing.

I have logging turned on, and that last one returns:

```
b5063beaaa3c80c2ad85635ddb1c5fac3da6b5510e9ef332c9e0df0c9abdd45a mydomain.me [01/Dec/2020:01:57:47 +0000] 73.202.134.48 b5063beaaa3c80c2ad85635ddb1c5fac3da6b5510e9ef332c9e0df0c9abdd45a 116EA2ED16AA56DE REST.GET.NOTIFICATION - "GET /mydomain.me?notification= HTTP/1.1" 200 - 115 - 15 - "-" "S3Console/0.4, aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.888 Linux/4.9.217-0.3.ac.206.84.332.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.262-b10 java/1.8.0_262 vendor/Oracle_Corporation" - noe+YUO+FeYaIukSpTTKl9npt1R0+uAr4Hqzx/mQge2bfhydBiiquR9EWG3iGanDRjK/EagN5Ss= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA AuthHeader s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2
```

CloudFront is running some Java library?

`curl -v https://mydomain.me/c/index.html` works fine.

I assume I have misconfigured CloudFront, but cannot figure out how.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the CloudFront Distribution ID
2. Select the tab "Origins and Origin Groups"
3. Click the checkbox for the first item under "Origins" (assuming you only have one)
4. Click "Edit"
5. Change the "Origin Domain Name" to
   "mydomain.me.s3**-website**-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" (following your
   example)
6. Click "Yes, Edit"

I've done this a hundred times, I know this is a requirement, and it bites me every time!

Comment: I stared at this for maybe 10 minutes before realizing you had added `-website` in the middle of that domain name.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes that’s it. You effectively use the external s3 url that you would access if you were hosting it from there. The reason I always fall for it, is because the origin in CloudFront is always a select box!